# Remove all the rows except one with the EXCEPT SQLite command

Tags: sqlite, except

From a dataset **character** that has a name column, I want to query the two names in with the shortest and longest names, as well as their respective lengths and when there is more than one smallest or largest name, I choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

With that query, I get all the shortest and longest names (**A**)

```
SELECT 
    name, LENGTH(name) AS LEN 
FROM 
    character 
WHERE 
    length(name) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM character) 
    OR length(name) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(name)) FROM character)
```

With this one, I get all the shortest names except the first alphabetically ordered one (**B**)

```
SELECT 
    name, LENGTH(name) AS LEN 
FROM 
    character 
WHERE 
    length(name) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(name)) FROM character) 
ORDER BY 
    name DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2;
```

When I try to remove **B** from **A**

```
A EXCEPT B
```

I would expect to keep the first shortest name but It does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `OFFSET 2` in your **B** query, you don't get:
*all the shortest names except the **first 1** alphabetically ordered*
Instead you get:
 
*all the shortest names except the **first 2** alphabetically ordered*,
because this is what `OFFSET 2` does: it **skips** the first 2 rows.
Also another problem with your code is the `ORDER BY` clause in your **B** query.
If you have this:

```
SELECT name,LENGTH(name) AS LEN FROM character 
WHERE length(name) = (select max( LENGTH(name)) from character ) 
or length(name) = (select min( LENGTH(name)) from character) 
EXCEPT
SELECT name,LENGTH(name) AS LEN FROM character 
WHERE length(name) = (select min( LENGTH(name)) from character) 
ORDER BY name desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2;
```

you may think that the `ORDER BY` clause (and `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`) is applied only to your **B** query, but this is not how it is interpreted.
Actually `ORDER BY` (and `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`) is applied to the **whole query** after the rows are returned.
To get the results that you want by using code similar to yours you must use a subquery to wrap your **B** query, like this:

```
SELECT name,LENGTH(name) AS LEN FROM character 
WHERE length(name) = (select max( LENGTH(name)) from character ) 
or length(name) = (select min( LENGTH(name)) from character) 
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT name,LENGTH(name) AS LEN FROM character 
  WHERE length(name) = (select min( LENGTH(name)) from character) 
  ORDER BY name desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(name), name) rn_min,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC, name) rn_max
    FROM character
)

SELECT name, LENGTH(name) AS LEN
FROM cte
WHERE 1 IN (rn_min, rn_max)
ORDER BY LENGTH(name);
```